# handleSubmit is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component, onsubmit

I'm working on a project and it keeps telling me "handleSubmit" nor defined although it is already defined.

This is my FormSubmit component (Function component)

```
    return (
    <Card>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h2 style={{color:'black'}}> How would you rate your service with us </h2>
        <RatingSelect select={(rating)=>setRating(rating)}/>
        <div className="input-group">
          <input type="text" onChange={getText} placeholder="Write a Review" value={text}/>
          {/* <button type="submit"> Send </button> */}
          <Button type='submit' version='primary' isDisabled={btnDisabled}/>
        </div>
        {message?<div className="message">{message}</div>:null}
      </form>
    </Card> 
  );
```

and this is a function

```
    const handleSubmit=()=>{
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(e);
        }
```

Comment: Missing passing the `onSubmit` event object to your `handleSubmit` handler.

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing `e` into the `handleSubmit` function, yet you are trying to refer to it in the body of the function.

Try this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e);
    }
```

Comment: I did that too, nothing worked for me @Arturr Karlov

Comment: You should probably post your whole component's code, as the issue might be elsewhere.

Comment: Never mind, it was my mistake. I was calling it on another function. Thanks @Artur

Comment: works for me your solution

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass event object inside your handleSubmit function like this

```
     const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log(e);
     }
```

otherwise it will not run give this error Line 26:5: 'e' is not defined

Answer (score -1):

use the handleSubmit function in onSubmit of the form tag in the react js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).